# GenomicRanges add coverage

Tags: r

I'm working on RNA seq data and trying to plot average coverage profiles by genotype, similarly to what is done here

**RNA seq Coverage per genotype (Source: pickrell et al, Nature, 2010)**

[image]

To do this plot, I have bigwig files from 100 individuals, that contain coverage information from RNA-seq data (in a specific region) and that I read in R, as GenomicRanges objects.

this gives me GRanges objects such as those obtained in the following toy example :

> gr1=GRanges(seqname=1,range=IRanges(start=c(1,5,10,15,30,55), end=c(4,9,14,29,39,60)))
>
> gr1$cov=c(3,1,8,6,2,10)
>
> gr2=GRanges(seqname=1,range=IRanges(start=c(3,20,24), end=c(7,23,26)))
>
> gr2$cov=c(3,5,3)
>
> start=unique(sort(c(ranges(gr1)@start,ranges(gr2)@start)))
>
> gr1

```
GRanges object with 6 ranges and 1 metadata column:
seqnames    ranges strand |       cov
   <Rle> <IRanges>  <Rle> | <numeric>
       1  [ 1,  4]      * |         3
       1  [ 5,  9]      * |         1
       1  [10, 14]      * |         8
       1  [15, 29]      * |         6
       1  [30, 39]      * |         2
       1  [55, 60]      * |        10 
        -------
 seqinfo: 1 sequence from an unspecified genome; no seqlengths
```

> gr2

```
GRanges object with 3 ranges and 1 metadata column:
seqnames    ranges strand |       cov
   <Rle> <IRanges>  <Rle> | <numeric>
       1  [ 3,  7]      * |         3
       1  [20, 23]      * |         5
       1  [24, 26]      * |         3
       -------
 seqinfo: 1 sequence from an unspecified genome; no seqlengths
```

The problem is that I have these per individual (gr1 and gr2 would be 2 different individuals), and I'd like to combine them to create a genomic ranges object that gives me the total coverage at each position across individuals, 1 and 2
that would look as follows :

> gr3

```
GRanges object with 6 ranges and 1 metadata column:
seqnames    ranges strand |       cov
   <Rle> <IRanges>  <Rle> | <numeric>
       1  [ 1,  2]      * |         3
       1  [ 3,  4]      * |         6 (=3+3)
       1  [ 5,  7]      * |         4 (=1+3)
       1  [ 8,  9]      * |         1
       1  [10, 14]      * |         8
       1  [15, 19]      * |         6
       1  [20, 23]      * |         11 (=6+5)
       1  [24, 26]      * |         9 (=6+3)
       1  [27, 29]      * |         6
       1  [30, 39]      * |         2
       1  [55, 60]      * |        10
```

Does anyone know a simple way to do this ? or am I doomed ?

Thanks for your answers.

PS:
my data isn't stranded, but if you have it for stranded data it's even better.

PPS: Ideally, I would also like to be able to to a multiplication, or apply any function with two arguments x and y, instead of simply adding the coverage.

Answer (score 5):

It's been almost a year, but here's my answer for future reference.

Whenever I don't find a function to do a task such as this one directly, I simply expand the `GRanges` objects to single-bp resolution. This allows me to perform any required operation on the metadata columns treating them as simple `data.frame` columns, since the `IRanges` are now matched between the two `Granges` objects.

In the specific case of this question, the following works.

```
### Sort seqlevels
# (not necessary here, but in real world examples,
# with multiple sequences, you will want to do this)
gr1 <- sort(GenomeInfoDb::sortSeqlevels(gr1))
gr2 <- sort(GenomeInfoDb::sortSeqlevels(gr2))

### Add seqlengths
# (this corresponds to the actual sequence lengths;
# here we use the highest position between the two objects: 60)
seqlengths(gr1) <- 60

### Make 1-bp tiles covering the genome
# (using either one of gr1 and gr2 as a reference)
bins <- GenomicRanges::tileGenome(GenomeInfoDb::seqlengths(gr1),
                                  tilewidth=1,
                                  cut.last.tile.in.chrom=TRUE)

### Get coverage signal as Rle object
gr1_cov <- coverage(gr1, weight="cov")
gr2_cov <- coverage(gr2, weight="cov")

### Get average coverage in each bin
# (since the bins are 1-bp wide, this just keeps the original coverage value)
gr1_bins <- GenomicRanges::binnedAverage(bins, gr1_cov, "binned_cov")
gr2_bins <- GenomicRanges::binnedAverage(bins, gr2_cov, "binned_cov")

### Make final object:
# We can now sum the values in the metadata columns
# Addressing the PPS, you could do any other operation or apply a function
gr3 <- gr1_bins
gr3$binned_cov <- gr1_bins$binned_cov + gr2_bins$binned_cov
```

This yields the final `GRanges` object at single-bp resolution.

```
> gr3

GRanges object with 60 ranges and 1 metadata column:
     seqnames    ranges strand | binned_cov
        <Rle> <IRanges>  <Rle> |  <numeric>
 [1]        1    [1, 1]      * |          3
 [2]        1    [2, 2]      * |          3
 [3]        1    [3, 3]      * |          6
 [4]        1    [4, 4]      * |          6
 [5]        1    [5, 5]      * |          4
 ...      ...       ...    ... .        ...
[56]        1  [56, 56]      * |         10
[57]        1  [57, 57]      * |         10
[58]        1  [58, 58]      * |         10
[59]        1  [59, 59]      * |         10
[60]        1  [60, 60]      * |         10
-------
seqinfo: 1 sequence from an unspecified genome
```

To compress it and get the exact `gr3` in the question, we can do the following.

```
### Compress back to variable-width IRanges (by cov)
gr3_Rle <- coverage(gr3, weight='binned_cov')
gr3 <- as(gr3_Rle, "GRanges")

### Drop 0-score rows
gr3 <- gr3[gr3$score > 0]

### Rename metadata column
names(mcols(gr3)) <- 'cov'

> gr3

GRanges object with 11 ranges and 1 metadata column:
       seqnames    ranges strand |       cov
          <Rle> <IRanges>  <Rle> | <numeric>
   [1]        1  [ 1,  2]      * |         3
   [2]        1  [ 3,  4]      * |         6
   [3]        1  [ 5,  7]      * |         4
   [4]        1  [ 8,  9]      * |         1
   [5]        1  [10, 14]      * |         8
   [6]        1  [15, 19]      * |         6
   [7]        1  [20, 23]      * |        11
   [8]        1  [24, 26]      * |         9
   [9]        1  [27, 29]      * |         6
  [10]        1  [30, 39]      * |         2
  [11]        1  [55, 60]      * |        10
  -------
  seqinfo: 1 sequence from an unspecified genome
```